# Prove that a Diophantine equation $ax^3 + by^2 = c$ has or doesn't have integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I got a diophantine equation, specifically $5x^3 + 4y^2 = 535$ where I have to prove that there are or are not integer solutions.

I tried using modular artimetic, this is my process:
$$4y^2 = 535 - 5x^3$$
$y^2$ mod 5 can be either 0, 1 or 4 (-1).
$$4y^2 ≡ 0\textrm{ (mod 5)}$$
5 divides the right hand side, so $y = 5t$. Furthermore:
$$4(5t)^2 = 535 - 5x^3$$
$$100t^2 = 535 - 5x^3$$
$$20t^2 = 107 - x^3$$

But now I get stuck. 107 is a prime number and unfortunately its relatively large to deal with. I can rewrite this as $x^3 = 107 - 20t^2$, but I don't know where to proceed from here.

Comment: Have you tried some small integer values of $x$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I got two solutions that way, however I cannot guarantee that these are the only ones

Comment: Try $x=3,y=10$? I think this is really hard...

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=-5x, Y=10y$ then we get Weierstrass form of the elliptic curve $Y^2 = X^3+13375$.
This curve  has only two integral points, according to the magma online calculator as follows.

IntegralPoints($[0,0,0,0,13375]$);

It says that all integral points are $( -15 ,\pm 100)$.
See [related info MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52979/integer-points-on-the-elliptic-curve-y2-x317)